# What is the difference between "systemctl start" and "systemctl enable"?

Tags: systemd, services, mariadb

I installed MariaDB server to my machine. While setting up, I was met with the problem of whether I should have it enabled all the time, as the documentation I follow suggests with these steps:

```
sudo yum install mariadb mariadb-server 
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service  
sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

Comment: You can also `enable` *and* `start` with the `--now` swich of `enable` subcommand, eg: `systemctl enable sshd --now`. The same is true for `disable` command to also `stop` the service.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

`systemctl start` and `systemctl enable` do different things.

`enable` will hook the specified unit into relevant places, so that it will automatically start on boot, or when relevant hardware is plugged in, or other situations depending on what's specified in the unit file.

`start` starts the unit right now.

`disable` and `stop` are the opposite of these, respectively.

This means that when you first install MariaDB, you might want to run `systemctl enable mariadb.service` to enable it so it starts on boot. You might also want to run `systemctl start mariadb.service`, or just reboot, in order to start MariaDB. To stop MariaDB, run `systemctl stop mariadb.service` (it will start again on next boot or when you manually start it). To disable it so it doesn't start on boot anymore, run `systemctl disable mariadb.service`.

Update:

As noted in gerardw's answer, starting from [version 220](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/57ab2eabb8f92fad5239c7d4492e9c6e23ee0678), released in may 2015, both `enable` and `disable` started to take the optional `--now` switch in order to also start or stop the unit, depending on the used command.

To both disable and stop a unit with the same command, use `systemctl disable mariadb.service --now`. Similarly, to both enable and start a unit, use `systemctl enable mariadb.service --now`.

Source: [systemctl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/systemctl.1.html)

Comment: ++++ for clear explaination

Comment: So when should we type systemctl enable? Everytime we want to run the systemd service?

Comment: No, when you want to make it start automatically. If you want to stop it from starting automatically then you run `systemctl disable`.

Comment: That means, is the service start as root ? How can I start service as another user on boot ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara Use the `--user`option.

Answer (score 26):

From [the `systemctl` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/systemctl.1.html):

```
enable NAME...
   Enable one or more unit files or unit file instances, as specified
   on the command line. This will create a number of symlinks as
   encoded in the "[Install]" sections of the unit files. After the
   symlinks have been created, the systemd configuration is reloaded
   (in a way that is equivalent to daemon-reload) to ensure the
   changes are taken into account immediately. Note that this does not
   have the effect of also starting any of the units being enabled. If
   this is desired, either --now should be used together with this
   command, or an additional start command must be invoked for the
   unit.
   ...
   Enabling units should not be confused with starting (activating)
   units, as done by the start command. Enabling and starting units is
   orthogonal: units may be enabled without being started and started
   without being enabled. Enabling simply hooks the unit into various
   suggested places (for example, so that the unit is automatically
   started on boot or when a particular kind of hardware is plugged
   in). Starting actually spawns the daemon process (in case of
   service units), or binds the socket (in case of socket units), and
   so on.
```

Essentially, `enable` marks the service for starting up on boot, and `start` actually starts the service immediately.

Comment: when should we enable? Do we only need to do it once?

Comment: @Goldname You enable it the first time you need it started on the next boot. Only once is enough,

Comment: What about when we edit it? Will we need to re-enable?

Comment: @Goldname you don't need to reenable it.

Comment: Thanks, and the same goes if the file is moved to a different directory and/or the system is rebooted?

Answer (score 16):

As of systemctl version 220, *enable* and *disable* support a *--now* switch to start / stop services concurrent with the enabling / disabling.

e.g. `systemctl --now enable foobar.service`

Use `systemctl --version` to check your installed version.

Comment: I just used this successfully in systemctl for systemd 219 (on CentOS 7)

Comment: The systemd github repo says 220, but perhaps CentOS backported the update. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/dd95b381b26369c02a3ca03585184cb2ea17295b/NEWS#L3043-L3046